# Setting Rds(Ron) for PMOS for LDO

Tags: power-electronics, ldo, linear-regulator, pspice, pmos

I am modeling **LDO** using [ZXCL280 Datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXCL260.pdf). By understanding datasheet dropout voltage of the PMOS is seen as `1.46Ω`(From page 5 `Ron=Vdrop/Id = 220mA/150mA` ). I assumed this Ron is including **Rs** and **Rd** (Source and Drain resistance). So while calculating **Kp** value using this formula

```
Ron=1/Kp(Vsg-Vt)
```

[image: Dropout Voltage]

Considering maximum current as **150mA** dropout voltage is **220mV** from the dropout vs drain current plot

```
Vsg-Vt= Vsd = Vin-Vout = 220mV
```

I am assuming Vout to be 1.8V so Vin will be 2.02V

By substituting values to find Kp

```
Kp=1/1.46*(220mV) =3.24A/V^2
```

I began to simulate dropout test case schematic and waveform is as below

[image: Model Card]

[image: Schematic]

[image: Waveform]

I this can be corrected by adding Rs and Rd in the model card to add up to Ron(Rds)
But i should have got `1.46Ω` without adding. Is there anything that I am missing or wrong?

Second Method:

I rearranged **Id** equation to find Kp (this is the only value that i get to set Ron in PSpice model card)

```
Kp=W*Id*2/L*(Vsg-Vt)^2
```

**W** and **L** is 1 default so,

```
Kp= (150mA)*2/(220mA)^2 = 6.198 A/V^2
```

But even this method didn't attain any joy

[image: Model Card 2]

[image: Dropout Image]

Is this the right way of setting Ron(Rds), if **Vsg**(Vgs) is not mentioned or given ? If Vsg is provided  how should I proceed and If not provided how should proceed ? 
How shall I look at output and Input characteristics relation with **Ron**?

Comment: Why not just RDS(ON) as a model parameter?

Comment: Since I am embedding individual characteristics so first was dropout, I belive kp is dependent on dropout. Is there any other parameters dependent?

Comment: Drop-out is dependent on RS and RD both of which are zero as default: https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jan/spice/spice.MOSparamlist.html. You are operating in the triode version of the MOSFET remember.

Comment: So total resistance is Ron + Rs + Rd in which Ron is set by kp. But how shall I assume Vg?

Comment: How shall I view Ron for PMOS in output charateristicts? Can you share a activity or document which will help me understand?

Comment: No not really. Why can't you pick a model that allows RDS(on) to be defined.

Comment: As previously mentioned in the question I am modeling LDO behavior and since understanding in depth would help this community and eliminate the gaps of questions and answers.

Comment: I can't help then.

Comment: Just a couple of points: 1) the MOS model you've picked is for integrated ones and do not fit with discretes, use VMOS instead. 2) MOS parameters are so widely spread that is really not worthwhile spending time in tuning a model to match something it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume L=0.6u, Imax=150mA

```
W/L  =  2*Idmax/un*Cox(Vdsat)^2 

W/0.6u= 2*(150mA)/34u*(220m)^2

W/0.6u = 182304.32

W = 109.38mm

rds= Vdrop/Imax = 220m/150m = 1.46Ω (Total resistance to be offered)
```

Add the above calculated W,L,Kp in model card and simulate, Check the drop out and add the remaining resistance by subtracting it with total resistance.

[image: Dropout Voltage]