# LDO datasheet parameter extraction

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, datasheet, ldo, modeling

In similarity to previous question [Ron setting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487645/setting-rdsron-for-pmos-for-ldo) of LDO. Unfortunately I assumed gain of the error amplifier and trial and error method I matched with dropout curve in the datasheet.

[image: Dropout]

Query: How to extract gain of error amplifier from LDO datasheet and what data is required to be understood or procured to set Ron of pass element (PMOS) in LDO. (I felt this is inter-related).I am assuming there is a generic LDO which will help for modifications.

I am assuming this is the initial step in understanding the modeling of LDO. Building a loop then adding features to it.

Answer (score 1):

The pass element is a PMOS, so when it is fully ON, it will behave as a resistor RdsON whose value depends on temperature and Vgs. This is why dropout voltage graphs are all straight lines.

In dropout mode, when Vin is too low, the "opamp" in the internal schematic will be clipped, its output will be the lowest possible voltage (probably GND) to get the FET to turn on as much as possible. So the FET's Vgs is equal to the input supply voltage.

So the subtlety about dropout voltage in PMOS based LDOs is that it depends on the input voltage since that's what determines the available FET Vgs.

In dropout, the internal error amplifier is clipped, so dropout voltage has no relation to any characteristics of the internal amplifier, except its minimum output voltage. So your method of determining the gain of the error amp from dropout voltage cannot work. You'd have to use the output impedance of the LDO as a starting point instead.

In your model, dependent voltage source E1 is not a good model as its output voltage can go below ground, which is not possible in a real LDO. So it will turn the FET ON more than a real LDO would, which will result in incorrect dropout voltage.

If you want to get the FET's characteristics from dropout voltage, remove the error amp and connect its gate to ground, simulating a clipped error amp.

Comment: Clipping on the gate using diode lower clamp helped me. Can you shed some light on output impedance or open loop gain plot will help me in determining gain of error amplifier.Low frequency gain will be composed of pmos , feedback divider, error amplifier gains?.

Comment: Yes, output impedance is dVout/dIout. Consider a small output voltage variation dVout, this will cause an output current variation dIout that is PMOS transconductance x error amp gain x feedback divider